# AngularJS - passing a value to a function for the second time returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined, angularjs-ng-click

I'm new to Angular and on my way to learn while bulding a website I've stopped with a really stupid moment.
I have a function inside a controller that is supposed to be called on ng-click event, I'm passing an 'id' value to it and using that 'id' it's supposed to search an array of *presenters*(objects) returning and assigning to $scope.presenter the one that I'm looking for. The thing is that the functions works ok for the the first time, but when I'm trying to call it again using a next/previous button the console log returns that the 'id' is undefined. Here is the controller code:

```
angular.module('fpl15App').controller('PresentersCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {

    $('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});

    $scope.showDetails = false;
    $scope.currentPresenter = {};


    $scope.getPresenterDetails = function( presenterId ) {
        var id = presenterId - 1;

        console.log(id);

        $scope.showDetails = true;

            var i=0, len=$scope.presenters.length;

            for (; i<len; i++) {
              if (+$scope.presenters[i].id === +id) {
                return $scope.currentPresenter = $scope.presenters[i];
              }
            }
            return null;

    };

    $scope.hideOverlay = function(){
        $scope.showDetails = false;
    }; 


    $scope.presenters = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'adam_wolf',
            thumb: 'images/presenters/adam_wolf.jpg',
            bio: 'lorem ipsum'
        }.
        ...
        {
            id: 15,
            name: 'aimee_nicotera',
            thumb: 'images/presenters/aimee_nicotera.jpg',
            bio: 'lorem ipsum'
        }
    ];
  });
```

end here is the view code:

```
<div class="row" id="presenters">
  <div class="col-md-12 above-element" id="presenter-overlay" ng-show="showDetails">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-6 motion-container animated" ng-class="{fadeInRight : showDetails}">
      <div class="col-md-12 skew-container bg-yellow no-pad">
        <div class="skew-content col-md-6 no-pad">
          <div class="row presenter-image-container">
            <div class="col-md-6 flex-container name-holder">
              <h2>{{currentPresenter.name}}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 no-pad image-holder">
              <figure><img src="{{currentPresenter.image}}" alt=""></figure>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row bg-white presenter-bio-container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
              <p>{{currentPresenter.bio}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row bg-white presenter-navigation">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 no-pad"> <span class="presenter-nav" ng-click="getPresenterDetails({{currentPresenter.id - 1}})"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></i> Prev </span> </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 no-pad"> <span class="presenter-nav" ng-click="getPresenterDetails({{currentPresenter.id + 1}})"> Next <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i> </span> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 under-element">
    <ul id="presenters-list">
      <li class="presenter animation"  ng-repeat="presenter in presenters"> <a ng-href="" ng-click="getPresenterDetails({{presenter.id}})"><img ng-src="{{presenter.thumb}}" alt="{{presenter.name}}"></a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make jsfiddle or plunkr example

Comment: You do not need the double curly braces in ng-click, i.e. convert these: `ng-click="getPresenterDetails({{presenter.id}})"` to: `ng-click="getPresenterDetails(presenter.id)"`. Other than that, try providing a fiddle...

Comment: thx for the hints, I manged to fix but I'm not sure what was the real reason because I've changed 2 things in the code: 1 - created a data service to call the presenters from a json file, 2 - created a filter to lookup the scope.presenters.